# Show multiple markers in google maps

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create multiple Markers for google maps. I started out with a `Set<Marker> markers = Set();`, then made a loop over a List and added Markers to `markers`

```dart
Marker resultMarker = Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(currentLocation.id),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "${currentLocation.title}", snippet: "$snippet"),
            position: LatLng(currentLocation.coordinates[1], currentLocation.coordinates[0]),
          );

markers.add(resultMarker);
```

I then tried returning a widget of:

```dart
GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: _cameraPosition, zoom: 11.0),
          onMapCreated: (controller) => mapController = controller,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
          markers: markers,
);
```

But I only get the first marker and not all of them. How can I get all markers?

Comment: Are you sure that `markers.length` is more than one?

Comment: @P4yam Yups. It's 3

Comment: Just a complete shot in the dark, but if the values are for any reason async and they're all at the current location, it could be possible they are all updating to the most recent current location. This would mean they might be displayed but are just on top of each other. I cannot tell if you are adding three of the result markers to the markers list or if you have two predefined markers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one worked for me:

```
List<Marker> markers = <Marker>[];
```

and inside your loop:

```
    markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(currentLocation.id),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "${currentLocation.title}", snippet: "$snippet"),
        position: LatLng(currentLocation.coordinates[1], currentLocation.coordinates[0]),

     )
   );
```

make sure that markers data are correct since google map does not show markers with invalid `LatLng` ( try to test with dummy data)

and then

```
GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(38.9647,35.2233),
        zoom: 9.0,
      ),
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        _controller.complete(controller);
      },
    )
```